# Spaces with given covering group

Tags: algebraic-topology

Given a topological space $X$ and a finite group $G$, can we construct a covering space $Y$ of $X$, such that the full covering transformation group is isomorphic to $G$. (We may assume some conditions, if required, such as connectedness, path-connectedness etc.)

Comment: The answer is no, in general. $\pi_1 X$ would have to contain a group isomorphic to $G$ for this to be true.

Comment: Ryan's comment is the correct answer, but this might be helpful for insight.  Let $F$ be a finite set.  Then the covering spaces of $X$ with $|F|$ sheets correspond exactly to the representations $\pi_1(X)\rightarrow Aut(F)$.  Basically, when you go around a loop you reattach $F$ to itself using the chosen automorphism.  Then you can translate between geometric statements and algebraic ones, e.g. the covering space is connected if and only if $\pi_1(X)$ acts transitively on $F$.

Comment: One of the above comments should be added as an answer.

Comment: The first comment is not correct: group of covering transformations $G$ is not a subgroup of $\pi_1 X$, rather it is the quotient of the normalizer of $\pi_1 Y$ in $\pi_1 X$ by $\pi_1 Y$.  For example $G = \mathbb{Z}_n$ is the group of covering transformations of the $n$-fold cover of the circle, but $\pi_1 (S^1)$ does not contain $G$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no, in general.  Since $\pi_1(Y)\rightarrow \pi_1(X)$ is injective we can identify it with its image; then the group of deck transformations is isomorphic to $N(\pi_1(Y))/\pi_1(Y)$.  (Here, if $H\leq G$, then $N(H)=\{g\in G:gHg^{-1}=H\}$ is the *normalizer* of $H$ in $G$.  This is the largest subgroup of $G$ which contains $H$ as a normal subgroup.  Note that if $G$ is abelian, then for any subgroup $H\leq G$ we have $N(H)=G$.)  This is a purely algebraic condition: since subgroups of $\pi_1(X)$ correspond bijectively to (based) covering spaces, if we find a suitable subgroup we can find such a covering space.

This might be helpful for insight. Let $F$ be a finite set. Then the covering spaces of $X$ with $|F|$ sheets correspond exactly to the representations $\pi_1(X)\rightarrow Aut(F)$. Basically, when you go around a loop you reattach $F$ to itself using the chosen automorphism. Then you can translate between geometric statements and algebraic ones, e.g. the covering space is connected if and only if $\pi_1(X)$ acts transitively on $F$.

Comment: As Robert Bell pointed out in comments above, "contain a group" should be replaced by "admit a quotient".

Comment: Oops!  Thanks so much for catching this.  I'm changing the answer now.